# I am looking for a text editor allowing to save and edit a list of search and replace expressions (search in multiple files, a plus)

Tags: gui, search, text-editor, regex

I am looking for a text editor for linux (I am using Ubuntu) that is able to save, let me edit and choose among a list of search and replace list. I have looked around and cannot find what I am looking for.

I am currently using a combination of [Altsearch and replace](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer), an extension of Libreoffice, plus the search and replace window of Libreoffice because not all expressions work in the above extension (which allows to use a list of searches though). This is one reason why I am looking for a text editor.

Another one is that the books and articles initially edited in Libreoffice are finally made into md and latex documents.

I am familiar with BBedit which would be perfect, but it is only for Mac.

So, I would like to be able to use a text editor that:

0. Has a GUI interface
1. Allows the use of regex
2. Allows to store a list of search and replace expressions
3. Allows to edit this list easily
4. Allows to select which search and replace expression is used at a given time
5. Allows to search and replace in multiple files (this would be a plus)
6. Is multiplatform (Mac, Windows, Linux)
7. Is free and opensource (although if a good paid editor exists, I am open to it)

I hope that somebody can help.

Comment: We're not supposed to give software recommendations here as there could be a lot that could fit your needs.  However, `notepad++` for Windows or `notepadqq` for Linux can do what you are looking for covering most of your list.  Not sure about Mac platform.

Comment: eclipse? aptana? both are EDIs. I would suggest asking this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind and Terrance, I will ask the question in the link you provided!